# How to clear a session in Cypress, completely

Tags: cypress

I have this test where it logs via cy.request() in and creates the session object in before each:

```
    cy.request({
          method: 'POST',
          url: `${URL}/sessions`,
          body: {
            userName: 'xxx',
            password: 'yyy',
          },
        });
```

Then during the first test it logs out via the interface:

```
 cy.page()
  .get('button[logout="UserMainMenu"]')
  .should('be.lengthOf', 1).click({ force: true })...
```

That works until now. But then the next test starts, doing the beforeEach() again.

Then it tries to restore the session object. But can't and after a time out recreates it.

[image]

I would like to avoid this timeout, and started to add the following commands:

```
cy.clearAllCookies();
cy.clearAllLocalStorage();
cy.clearAllSessionStorage();
```

How ever this does not make a difference. It still recreates:

[image]

Current version of cypress: 12.4.1

Answer (score 4):

OK. I found it: to clear the complete session, it needs this command:

Cypress.session.clearAllSavedSessions()

(a logout via interface and login again (with same user) seems to inactivate the session)